# ffmpeg mp4 shows blurred frames after seeking in the video with internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4

I have a question regarding JWPlayer 5, IE and video encoding.
Basicly I use a Wowza server to stream my files. This works on all devices (windows, iOS and Android).
However when i play it in Internet Explorer, it behaves strange.
It plays fine, and the entire movie looks good without any issues. But when I seek in the video, it shows a line in the center of my video, like if the previous frame is still showing some part, and it refreshes after a few frames move in the video.
The frames itself are not broken, as if i just play the video without seeking it all looks good.
This does not happen in Chrome, Firefox or Safari, neither does this happen on android & iOS.
I've tested this with JW 6 as well, and it shows the same results for IE.

Altough it's showing fine on other browsers, I still believe it's an issue with encoding, as other videos do not show this behavior.

Example viewable here : http://www.mobileevolution.be/standardcode-withsmil.html

The FFMPEG code i use to convert any file (.avi in this case) to an MP4:

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -i "%1" -vcodec libx264 -strict experimental -c:a aac -profile:v baseline -level 3 -movflags faststart -bufsize 1000k -tune zerolatency -b:v 1000k -minrate 600k -maxrate 1500k "%5%71000k.mp4"
```

the %1, %5 and %7 are variables i send with a script.

I have tried various options, but could not figure out what the problem is.
I have also tried converting with handbrake, but this shows similar results.

My questions are:
Has anyone seen this before?
Does anyone know a solution?
What's wrong with my FFMPEG settings?

Thanks for any help,
Grts

**EDIT**
pictures:
http://www.mobileevolution.be/foto1.jpg
http://www.mobileevolution.be/foto2.jpg
console output:
http://www.mobileevolution.be/consoleoutput.txt

Comment: Please show the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: What you are describing is what happens when you seek a video to an arbitrary spot, not at a keyframe.  This will usually fix itself at the next keyframe.  Configure FFmpeg to output keyframes more often.  Beyond that, this is a client bug.

Comment: I've added the console output and 2 screenshots LordNeckbeard. Also: how can i solve this Brad? It isn't showing on other browsers, so it just seems like IE behavior. However if i was to make a .flv file and play this instead with the same code, it does not have this issue. But i don't want to make an flv file because this would mean yet another conversion... and i already have to do 3 for each video.

Comment: Btw, i've also tried to encode the file with -g 9999 thus adding 9999 keyframes, and it's not better, it's just different, instead of the line in the middle it just shows entirely blurry frames...

Comment: i also have the same problem. has your problem solved ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

apparently it really has to do with the client itself.
not really an encoding issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RononDex: I know that's an automated comment, but that _is_ the author.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ah well, didn't see that when reviewing. But still it is more like a comment than an asnwer.

Comment: Well there is no real "answer" ... it's just one of those "internet explorer does things differently than other browsers" ... as it always does :)